# Let syntax in Haskell

Tags: haskell, indentation

I have written the following solution for Problem 10 [(99 questions) in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) :

```
{-- using dropWhile and takeWhile --}
enc :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
enc [] = []
enc (x:xs) = (length $ takeWhile (==x) (x:xs), x) : enc (dropWhile (==x) xs)
```

I wanted to rewrite the same solution but this time using a let syntax .

```
{-- using dropWhile and takeWhile / more readable --}
enc' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
enc' [] = []
enc' (x:xs) = let num = length $ takeWhile (==x) (x:xs)
      rem = dropWhile (==x) (x:xs)
      in (num, x) : enc' rem
```

The second example is not working . The error is:

```
*Main> :l Problem10.hs
Compiling Main             ( Problem10.hs, interpreted )

Problem10.hs:16:38: parse error on input `='
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Where line 16 is this one: `rem = dropWhile (==x) (x:xs)`

Any suggestions ?

LE: Yes, it was an indentation problem . It seems that my editor (Notepad++) should be configured a little to avoid problems like this .

Comment: Could this be an indentation error?  You might need to push the rest of the lines after the let statement forward to match.  Not sure if this is the culprit, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned this is an indentation problem, it's caused by the line starting with  `rem` being less indented then the previous line so it is not parsed as belonging to the previous `let` statement. A good way of determining how to indent in Haskell is the [offside rule](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.offside) from [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/).

Also it is often a good idea to drop to a new line when starting your function with a `let` statement so to avoid wide indentation, like this:

```
enc :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
enc []     = []
enc (x:xs) = 
  let num = length . takeWhile (==x) $ x:xs
      rem = dropWhile (==x) (x:xs)
  in (num, x) : enc rem
```

Answer (score 4):

As @templatetypedef points out, it **is** indeed the indentation. The `rem =` needs to be aligned with the `num =`.